# Is it possible to have different signature?

Tags: haxe, neko

I have the following code :

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace("Haxe is great!");
        var api:Api = new Api();
        api.doAdd(1,1);
    }
}

class Api {

    public function new(){}

    public function doAdd( x : Int, y : Int ) {
        trace( x + y );
    }

    public function doAdd( x : Int, y : Int , z : Int) {
        trace( x + y + z);
    }
}
```

[Here is a link to a try Haxe code](http://try.haxe.org/#92343)

If I try to compile this code, I get an error : ```Duplicate class field declaration : doAdd````

My question is, is there anyway to have two methods with differents signatures in haxe ?

Comment: I googled it and it doesn't look like it's supported https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haxelang/feujdbvrrrQ/1rroSz4eHncJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Java and C# targets, the following works:

```
@:overload
public function doAdd(x:Int, y:Int) {
    trace(x + y);
}

@:overload
public function doAdd(x:Int, y:Int, z:Int) {
    trace(x + y + z);
}
```

On other targets, the syntax for `@:overload` is a bit different and only works for externs as far as I understand it. There's an example in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/haxelang/@$3Aoverload/haxelang/A-lXBBOiYkc/cK3eunEPq7YJ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try to work with that. For information, I am targetting the neko platform.

Comment: @MaximeMangel Wouldn't recommend that though. Overloading is there just for compatibilit with existing backend APIs for some backends.It isn't haxe way of doing things and shouldn't be usually used. It also may introduce some hard to track errors on compilation stage(which I've encountered) which aren't even supposed to be fixed.

Comment: @stroncium Ok, I will try to figure a way to avoid the overloads so